# How to change the name of the pub packages folder?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a little problem with developing. For my projects I use the IDE, which has some folder layout conventions. Now I started to work with dart, but the [Pub Package Layout Conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) seems not to allow me to change the name of the "packages" folder to "applications".

Is there any way, how to change the Pub Package Layout Conventions in the settings file in sdk? My goal is, that running "pub get" downloads dependencies to another folder than packages folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rename the packages folder.